# How to animate view based on another view

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, constraints, uiviewanimation

The middle lock animates upwards faster than the top pane in my animation. How do I animate the middle lock so that it moves upwards alongside the top pane? To be more specific, I want the middle locks center to always align with the top panes bottom as it moves up and off the screen.

This is the code I currently have, `lockBorder` and `lockKeyhole` is what is referred to as "middle lock" which is moving upwards too fast compared to the `topLock`:

```
@IBOutlet var topLock: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bottomLock: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var lockBorder: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var lockKeyhole: UIImageView!


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    openLock()

}


func openLock() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.lockKeyhole.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(3.14))
        }, completion: { _ in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {

                var topFrame = self.topLock.frame
                topFrame.origin.y -= topFrame.size.height

                var bottomFrame = self.bottomLock.frame
                bottomFrame.origin.y += bottomFrame.size.height


                var lockBorderFrame = self.lockBorder.frame
                lockBorderFrame.origin.y -= self.view.frame.height

                var lockKeyholeFrame = self.lockKeyhole.frame
                lockKeyholeFrame.origin.y -= self.view.frame.height

                self.topLock.frame = topFrame
                self.bottomLock.frame = bottomFrame
                self.lockKeyhole.frame = lockKeyholeFrame
                self.lockBorder.frame = lockBorderFrame

                }, completion: { finished in

            })
        })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make it a subview of the top half?

Comment: @jtbandes Can you show how you would do that? I currently have everything in Storyboard.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand how it's set up by just looking at the code. What I'm recommending is that rather than `topLock` and `lockKeyhole`/`lockBorder` being sibling views, they should be subviews of `topLock`. Then you can just move `topLock` and it will take the others with it.

Comment: @jtbandes I'll see what I can do then based on your comments. Just to explain, Basically there are 4 images, you can confirm this by looking at the IBOutlets above, and these images are set up exactly like how the video starts. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adjusting `topFrame.origin.y` by `topFrame.size.height`, but you are adjusting `lockBorderFrame.origin.y` and `lockKeyholeFrame.origin.y` by `self.view.frame.height`. We can deduce that these adjustments are different amounts. I assume `topFrame.size.height` is one half of `self.view.size.height`. Since you're moving the lock views by twice the distance you're moving `topLock`, and both adjustments happen over the same 0.6 second interval, the lock views move twice as fast.

I assume you want to animate the lock views all the way off the screen, so it would be insufficient to move them by by only `topFrame.size.height`. That would leave the bottom half of the lock visible. You need to move the lock views so that their bottom edges are at the top edge of `self.view`.

This means that you need to set `lockBorder.frame.origin.y` to the negative of `lockBorder.frame.size.height`. It will move a total distance of `lockBorder.frame.size.height + lockBorder.frame.origin.y`, which happens to be equal to `lockBorder.frame.maxY`.

I assume that `lockBorder` is at least as large as `lockKeyhole`, so if we move all the views by `lockBorder.frame.maxY`, they will all be off the screen. And since we move them all the same distance, all the views will move together.

Note also that if you use constraints in your storyboard, then these views will snap back to their original positions as soon as you do almost anything else to the view hierarchy. So you should probably remove them from their superviews as soon as the animation finishes, unless you're hiding them in some other way (like by removing their superview from the view hierarchy).

Incidentally, the standard library defines `M_PI` for you.

```
func openLock() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.lockKeyhole.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {
                let yDelta = self.lockBorder.frame.maxY

                self.topLock.center.y -= yDelta
                self.lockKeyhole.center.y -= yDelta
                self.lockBorder.center.y -= yDelta
                self.bottomLock.center.y += yDelta
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.topLock.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.lockKeyhole.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.lockBorder.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.bottomLock.removeFromSuperview()
            })
    })
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Quick question, I usually get the animations to work, but I sometimes get it wrong when it comes to thinking about the math and code, so is there a visual tool that helps with this? Like PaintCode helps with drawing, is there anything that helps with this?

Comment: I don't know of such a tool.

Comment: No problem, thanks for answering and for such a great explanation of the answer you provided!

Comment: Hey Rob, I have an animation question and thought maybe you could help out - please take a look if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828067/how-to-make-image-spin-animation